# issue in radio button if there is in for loop

Tags: php, html, radio-button

i have

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="is_active_<?php echo $v['class_id'] ?>" id="is_active_<?php echo $v['class_id'] ?>" <?php if($v['display_online']==1){ echo ' checked'; }?> >
<label for="is_active_no_<?php echo $v['display_online'] ?>">Yes    </label>
<input type="radio" value="0" <?php if($v['display_online']==0){ echo 'checked'; }?> name="is_active_<?php echo $v['class_id'] ?>" id="is_active_<?php echo $v['class_id'] ?>">
<label for="active_yes_<?php echo $v['display_online'] ?>"> No  </label>
```

in for loop.
see image:- [image]
see html output:-

```
<input type="radio" id="is_active_47568" name="is_active_47568" checked="checked" value="1">
 <label for="is_active_no_1">Yes    </label>
<input type="radio" id="is_active_47568" name="is_active_47568" value="0">
<label for="active_yes_1">  No  </label>
```

but checked is not working what the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `echo checked='checked';`

Comment: hello @AlirezaFallah i have tried this but it also not worked.

Comment: Paste the HTML output that is generated by this code

Comment: maybe your `if`'s result is false!

Comment: maybe if($v['display_online']==0) is not true so it is not getting checked.check the value of the phhp variable.

Answer (score 0):

if name of radio button are same ie grouped then 'checked' will work only for one radio button...

Comment: hello @user1844933 each row has different group.

Comment: hello @user1844933 what is the problem in html output please tell me.